# how to auto-vectorize explicit multiplication in a loop

Tags: c, vectorization

```
// Computes product from (m+1) to (m+a)
unsigned long long compute_with_for_loop(unsigned long long a, unsigned long long m) {
    if (m < 1) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (m < 4) {
        unsigned long long result = 1;
        for (unsigned long long i = 1; i <= m; i++) {
            result *= (a+i);
        }
        return result;
    }
    unsigned long long result = 1;
    unsigned long long i = 1;
    for (; i < m; i+=4) {
        result *= (a+i) * (a+i+1) * (a+i+2) * (a+i+3);
    }
    if (i <= m) {
        for (; i <= m; i++) {
            result *= (a+i);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

The motivation is to compute `(a+m)!/m!` = `(a+m)(a+m-1)...(m+1)`
I know about `tgamma()` but I want to test if this is faster.

How do I force compiler to use vectorization? I tried adding `-march=native -ftree-vectorize -O3` but the `.lst` file did not include any vectorization.

Comment: `long long` or `int64_t` multiplication does not vectorize on x86 (at least not before AVX512). You could try multiplying some subproducts as `int32` and only do the final product as `int64`. You will likely get an overflow pretty soon, either way.

Comment: Or actually, do the multiplication in `double` -- since the lowest bits are all zero, since every other factor is even, you will be able to store almost all results without rounding errors inside `double` which would fit inside `int64`. For auto-vectorization, you may need to compile with some `-ffast-math` option.

Answer (score 0):

> The motivation is to compute (a+m)!/m! = (a+m)(a+m-1)...(m+1)
> I know about tgamma() but I want to test if this is faster.

Well, it depends on how tgamma() is calculated :)

probably, and for large numbers and large number of factors, you will probably can use the factorial approximation given by the Stirling formula `n! ~= sqrt(2*M_PI*n)(n/M_E)^n` (I think there's  a bettter approximation), using it to calculate it for `n!/m!`:

```
sqrt(n/m)*(n/M_E)^n/(m/M_E)^m
```

You can use a fast exponentiation algorithm to make the exponentiations faster than the iterative multiplications you make (you cannot contract them by squaring as you do in the fast exponentiation algorithm)

On the other side, the Gamma function is a problematic function as it has poles in all negative integers, and so, cannot easily be developed as a series over a big circle without incurring in slow convergence and so on.  IMHO the gamma function is calculated around point 1/2, and with a radius of 1/2 to cover the interval [0,1] with full precision without approaching the pole at -1, and use the recursive definition Gamma(p + 1) = p * Gamma(p) until you get p in the interval [0, 1].

But I'm sure there are better algorithms to calculate it than the one I have explained above.  A bit of google search will probably give you a better solution.